# PHP - Showing different text between different dates (3 Different Text to be shown)

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and i want to show 3 different text during different date periods.
e.g. 01/01 - 01/04 = TERM 1, 20/04 - 01/06 = TERM 2, 01/07 - 31/10 = TERM 3.
Can someone help me with that. I have not been able to write a code for that.
Thanking You In Advance.

Regards
Akshat Gupta

Comment: `echo '01/01 - 01/04 = TERM 1, 20/04 - 01/06 = TERM 2, 01/07 - 31/10 = TERM 3.'`;

Comment: Try to breakdown the date to days and months and then use some ifs.

Comment: @TomHart actually this is not what i was expecting as i have to echo Term 1 between 1st of jan and 1st of april (Example)

Comment: Your question isn't clear, Post what you've tried so far and we might be able to better help you.

Comment: @satchcoder can you be more precise with that?

Comment: 1.get current date (date()). Break it down to days and months (explode()) and then some ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Akshat please find the simplified solution below

```
<?php 
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
if(strtotime($current_date)>strtotime('2015-01-01') && strtotime($current_date)<strtotime('2015-04-01'))
{
    echo "TERM 1";
}
elseif(strtotime($current_date)>strtotime('2015-04-20') && strtotime($current_date)<strtotime('2015-06-01'))
{
    echo "TERM 2";
}
elseif(strtotime($current_date)>strtotime('2015-07-01') && strtotime($current_date)<strtotime('2015-10-31'))
{
    echo "TERM 3";
}
?>
```

I have tested it and its working fine

Comment: It works fine sir, but i would like if it could work with days and months only as i tried it is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by some if's...

so i write something can so such thing one year one year...for example from now on till next year it'll show term 1 and next year will show term 2 and go on... hope it helps..

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = date('Y/m');
echo $date;

if(date('Y')>="2015" && date('Y')<"2016" && date('m') >="02" && date('m')<"03" )
echo "term1";

if(date('Y')>="2016" && date('Y')<"2017" && date('m') >="02" && date('m')<"03" )
echo "term1";

if(date('Y')>="2017" && date('Y')<"2018" && date('m') >="02" && date('m')<"03" )
echo "term1";
```

i just echo the $date to show you how to get current system time...

the link below will help...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: There is no need of this much if conditions actually. The out put is correct but this much conditions will take much load

Comment: @Veerendra i appreciate your concern but this is for educational propose :| read my post...i even echo the current time...there is no need of it...because he said he is new to php and i tried my best to show him what he is going to do...hope you would understand me... <3